# Int Arraylist variable in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have to Execute Foreach loop Container in SSIS , for the list of IDs from a table.

What I want to do is to get to store the list of IDs in a SSIS variable.
I would like to know how to store list of IDs in a int variable. 
I am curious if anybody has idea about this or any url...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an object variable to store a list of ids